# Query string parameter to remove menu block in aspx popup

Tags: 2010, 2013, query-string, popup

I am using the following URL to display a popup: `var xVersionUrl = xAppWebUrl +  "/Lists/dlWerkinstructies/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + xItemId + "&VersionNo=" + versionId`

When clicked on the link I put the URL in I get the following popup:

[image]

Is there a way that I can remove the red outlined block? Preferably by using a query string parameter to the URL, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `IsDlg=1` or `isdlg=1`

```
var xVersionUrl = xAppWebUrl +  "/Lists/dlWerkinstructies/Forms/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1&ID=" + xItemId + "&VersionNo=" + versionId
```

If you send the page `IsDlg`, SharePoint forces the size of the window and disables the scrolling. If you send `isdlg`, SharePoint does nothing with it except for hiding the CSS elements.

Comment: yes, this works!

Answer (score 1):

Append IsDlg=1 to your url string